# How to set UIPageControl size correctly in iPad

Tags: uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a UIScrollView and a UIPageControl in my iPad app. I've placed them in the .xib file. My app supports landscape view only.

I try to set the width and height in code and it never looks right. I have a very simple case with 5 pages each set to a different color background to make sure my pages look right, but they never do, the colors overlap no matter what I do.

So my question is:

1. How can I set the size right in code (viewDidLoad?)?
2. Do I need to set the size for both UIScrollView and UIPageControl?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the code below. Here, I've done everything using code. Hope it can help you.

```c
int numberOfPages = 5 ;

UIScrollView *scrollQuestionList = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 70.0)];
scrollQuestionList.contentSize = CGSizeMake(numberOfPages*scrollQuestionList.frame.size.width, scrollQuestionList.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:scrollQuestionList];
scrollQuestionList.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
scrollQuestionList.delegate = self;
scrollQuestionList.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollQuestionList.pagingEnabled = YES;

CGFloat x = 0.0;

tagForBtns = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) 
{
    UIView *contentView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0.0, scrollQuestionList.frame.size.width, scrollQuestionList.frame.size.height)] autorelease];

    if (i%2 == 0)
    {
        [contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    }
    else
    {
        [contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
    }

    [scrollQuestionList addSubview:contentView];
    x+= scrollQuestionList.frame.size.width;
}
UIPageControl *pageCntrl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height - 70.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 25.0)];
pageCntrl.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
pageCntrl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[pageCntrl addTarget:self action:@selector(clickedPageControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
pageCntrl.currentPage = 0;    
[self.view addSubview:pageCntrl];
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are using xib then why are you setting width and height by using code. And also the problem you are facing I think because of autoresizing just try by modifying this hope it will work.

Comment: it' doesn't matter how I set the width & height, in IB or in code, it still doesn't work. Autoresizing didn't fix it either :(